# i need to find the sum of user entered values dynamically as user enters the values and display the sum of values autometically

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function() {
sum += parseInt($.text(this), 10);
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```

i tried above code but it is not applicable for dynamical values as user input values dynamically.I need my code to dynamically calculate the user entered values and display the sum of values as user enters the value irrespective of number of inputs.i am new to jquery please help me in coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could use some thing like this

### HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="elm" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="elm" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="elm" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="elm" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 5</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="elm" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>
            <label id="total">0</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

### jQuery

```
    $('body').on('keyup','.elm',function(e){
    //Check Key Press is Enter
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.elm').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != '' && !isNaN($(this).val())){
                sum += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });

        $('#total').text(sum);
    }
    else{
        var itemNum = $('#tbody tr').length + 1;
        var newRow = '<tr>'+
            '<td>Item'+itemNum+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
                '<input type="text" class="elm">'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
        $('#tbody').append(newRow);
    }
});
```

you could also use jquery's clone function for cloning a tr from the table. That's upon you.

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/y7ny6r5n/5/

Comment: just use parseFloat instead of parseInt and check condition modified

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little off, it should be:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val());
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

For form elements (`<input>`, `<textarea>`), you should use [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the input content.

Complete code:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});

$('.total').text(sum);
```